# Crear código automático en campo de tabla en Base de Datos Django 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo este modelo en la Base de Datos: `products_package` con un campo `code`.

Quiero crear un Código auto incremental utilizando este string `PCKG` mas el id del registro..

Es decir, si creo el registro 25 debería quedar así:

```
Code: PCKG25
```

Abajo creé mas o menos una función para que me entiendan que quiero hacer:

- Obtener el `id` del Registro
- Obtener el `string` del código
- Unificar `String` + `Id`
- Actualizar el campo

Soy bastante nuevo en Python y Django, así que algo no está bien en la función `get_auto_code`.

Resumiendo: Quiero crear un código autoincremental tomando en cuenta el `string` + el `id`

Acá el archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class products_package(models.Model):

     __AUTOCODE__ = 'PCKG'

    code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Code", max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Description")
    pieces = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Pieces")
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(
            products, verbose_name="Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(
        stock_location, verbose_name="Location", null=True, 


        blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code        


     def get_auto_code(self, **kwargs):
        code = super(products_package, self).get_auto_code(**kwargs)
         code_str = str(self.__AUTOCODE__ + self.id)
         code = self.code = code_str
         return code
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacerlo, respecto al campo, lo ideal es utilizar [señales](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch), específicamente la señal [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

Primero creamos nuestra señal (lo ideal seria que el atributo `__AUTOCODE__` no tenga guiones bajos, pues das a entender que es un atributo especial y no lo es, mejor es `AUTOCODE`, sin mas):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender = 'my_app.products_package')
def set_auto_code(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created'): # Entramos al if si se ha creado la instancia
        # Actualisamos la instancia
        sender.objects.filter(id = instance.id).update(code = instance.AUTOCODE + str(instance.id))
```

Esta señal la puedes poner en tu archivo `models.py` o en un archivo llamado `signals.py`, pero si lo quieres poner en este, deberás hacer unas modificaciones en unos archivos pero eso ya es otro tema.

De esta manera cada ves que se cree una instancia esta señal sera llamada y actualizara el campo `code`. Entonces el valor de del campo `code` siempre sera `'PCKG' + id`.

*(Una explicación corta de ¿Que son las señales en Django?, pues una señal es un disparador que se llama automáticamente después de un evento que 
ocurre en el ORM o en la db, para mas información visita la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch))*

---

Por otra parte si solo quieres "mostrar" el `AUTOCODE + id` por así decirlo, simplemente crea una función que la devuelva (pues es algo tedioso lo de la señal e innecesario si solo vas a mostrarlo en un template o algo así):

```
class products_package(models.Model):
    AUTOCODE = 'PCKG'

    ...

    def get_autocode(self):
        return self.AUTOCODE + str(self.id)
```

Bastara con hacer lo siguiente para obtener el `autocode`:

```
>>> instance.get_autocode()
PCKG25
```

Y eso seria todo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Perfect amigo, funcionó, no sabía de eso, revisaré la documentación.  Gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)

Answer (score 2):

Que tal si generas una propiedad que te haga el código que necesitas, no es indispensable guardarlo en base de datos mira este ejemplo

```
class products_package(models.Model):

     __AUTOCODE__ = 'PCKG'

    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Description")
    pieces = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Pieces")

    @property
    def code(self):
        return str(self.__AUTOCODE__ + str(self.id))
```

---

Ahora si lo quieres guardar puedes reescribir el metodo **`save`**(prefiera usar la señal **`post_save`**)

```
from django.db import models

class products_package(models.Model):

    __AUTOCODE__ = 'PCKG'

    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Description")
    pieces = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Pieces")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code        

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if (self.id is None):
            super().save(*kwargs)
        code_str = str(self.__AUTOCODE__ + self.id)
        self.code = code_str
        super().save(*kwargs)
```

Comment: Jack te olvidaste de algo, en el método `save()` el valor de `self.id` es `None` pues aun no se crea la instancia, prácticamente el valor de `self.code` es `'PCKGNone'`. Lo ideal seria llamar la función `save()` de la clase padre antes de generar el `code`, de esta manera ya se crea la instancia y existe el `id` de la instancia. También al momento de generar el `code` estas concatenando `str` con `int`, lo cual dará error, la forma correcta seria: `self.__AUTOCODE__ + str(self.id)`. Por cierto muy buena tu solución en cuanto al método `save()`! Saludos! :)

Comment: @JulioCesar al enviar la respuesta me quedo en la mente que algo se me olvidaba, mil gracias!

Comment: Suele pasar xd, Saludos! :)

Comment: Hola, Estoy probando la opción de Jack, y justamente me da el 'PCKGNone' como código. Julio, cuando dices  que "Lo ideal seria llamar la función save() de la clase padre antes de generar el code" a qué te refieres?? Para probar Coloqué el super().save antes del code_str = ... y nada, supongo que no es ahí. No busco que "me hagan la tarea" pero poco a poco voy aprendiendo y muchas gracias!

Comment: acabo de agregar un cambio @DDBCDVD debe funcionar salvo que tenga ya un code None

Comment: Listo, así también funciona! Mil Gracias!